# Distributing JxBrowser and demo

Tags: jxbrowser

I have downloaded the JxBrowser-6.23.1 demo and note that the demonstration browser, `jxbrowserdemo.jar`, within the `\demo\` directory still works even after removing all the platform-specific libraries from the `\lib\` directory and just leaving the 1,116KB `jxbrowser-6.23.1.jar`.

I assume the platform-specific files within the `\lib\` folder are the `CEF` binaries, so I'm wondering how JxBrowser has managed to distribute `CEF` in two files that are just over 1 megabyte in size? (1,116KB - `jxbrowser-6.23.1.jar` (in `\lib\`) and 104KB - `jxbrowserdemo.jar` (in `\Demo\`))

Obviously I must be missing something here, but how does the demonstration browser work without a reference to the platform-specific `CEF` libraries?

(I am on a Windows 10 64-bit machine)

---

### Edit

Creating a test project in IntelliJ also yields the same results, removing the specific cross-platform libraries has no impact on the browser working and all I need are two small libraries...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Chromium binary files have been already unpacked to some folder, for example, ~\AppData\Local\JxBrowser\browsercore-69.0.3497.12.6.23.1\

You should be able to see that folder listed in the JxBrowser log messages `INFO: Chromium binaries dir: ...` (to enable logging, please pass the JVM parameter `-Djxbrowser.logging.level=ALL`)

JxBrowser checks this location first, and only if files are not found there, tries to extract them from the platform-specific JAR files.

Also, JxBrowser does not use `CEF` binaries. The `jxbrowser-win32.jar`, `jxbrowser-win64.jar`, `jxbrowser-mac.jar`, `jxbrowser-linux64.jar` libraries are part of JxBrowser library. They contain Chromium binaries for the corresponding platform.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. I don't suppose you know if there is a way to not have it do this?

Comment: Chromium can't work with the packed binary files. They should be unpacked somewhere anyway. However, you can specify the location of the binary files in the following way: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000015146-chromium-binaries

Comment: That's actually what I meant, I just phrased it clumsily. Thank you for your help.